# Number of test cases predicted are less than the actual test data in LSTM

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I have been trying to predict the number of orders based on the time series data using **LSTM Keras.**

I have divided sample data with the training set contains 282 records while test set contains 82 records. I am using **look back window of 30** in order to predict the forecast for the test data.

But for some reason **predicted dataset contains only 40** records as opposed to expected 71 records in test data. What can be the reason behind it? is the lookup window that is causing the issue? I feel look back window is causing the issue. But how can I rectify it?

**It is important to keep such a high look back window**

```
def create_LSTM(trainX,testX,trainY,testY,look_back):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(1, look_back),activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='RMSProp')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=300, batch_size=4, verbose=1)
    trainpredict = model.predict(trainX,batch_size=4)
    testpredict  = model.predict(testX,batch_size=4) 
    testpredict = np.array(testpredict).reshape(len(testpredict),1)      
    print(testpredict) 
    print(len(testpredict))
    return trainpredict,testpredict
```

I am using the following function to create the data for LSTM which is causing the actual issue. how can I rectify it?

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
    #for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

Comment: What's `trainX` and `testX` shape? At a first glance, it seems your `input_shape` is wrong. The first dimension represents the sequence length (`look_back`, in your case) and the following ones represent the actual data shape.

Comment: Actually the function I am using to create a data for LSTM is actually causing an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem with `create_dataset`

When you get an element of the ndarray, you loose the rank associated with that element. This happens because if you are interested in that single element, then you don't need to retain the dimension `1`:

```py
x = np.random.randn(4, 4)
print(x, x.shape)
array([[ 1.37938213, -0.10407424, -0.356567  , -1.5032779 ],
   [-0.53166922,  0.98204605, -0.62052479,  0.99265612],
   [ 0.23046477, -0.17742399,  0.38283412,  0.24104468],
   [-0.78093724,  1.06833765, -1.22112772, -0.78429717]])
(4, 4)

print(x[0:3, 0], x[0:3, 0].shape)
array([ 1.37938213, -0.53166922,  0.23046477])
(3,)
```

So when you write `a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]`, you are taking a dataset of shape `(samples, features)` and getting a chunk of shape `(look_back,)`. After adding all a's to `dataX`, it becomes an ndarray of shape `(samples, look_back) = (len(dataset) - look_back - 1, look_back)`. However, the LSTM is expecting the shape `(samples, look_back, features)`, which in your case `(samples, look_back, 1)`.

If you change it to `a = dataset[i:(i + look_back)]`, then things will start to work. A better solution, however, is to use `TimeseriesGenerator`:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

batch_size = 4
look_back = 1
features = 1

d = np.random.randn(364, features)
train = TimeseriesGenerator(d, d,
                            length=look_back,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            end_index=282)
test = TimeseriesGenerator(d, d,
                           length=look_back,
                           batch_size=batch_size,
                           start_index=282)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=[look_back, features], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit_generator(train, epochs=1, verbose=1)
p_train = model.predict_generator(train)
p_test = model.predict_generator(test)
```

#### Further Comments on Other Sections

1. `model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(1, look_back),activation= 'relu'))` - the input shape should conform with `(length, features)`. In this case, where `length == features`, things would work out. You do need to update this code to `input_shape=(look_back, 1)` if you want a larger `look_back`.
2. `testpredict = np.array(testpredict).reshape(len(testpredict), 1)` - this is unnecessary. `Model#predict` already outputs a `ndarray` if you have a single output, and its shape is already `(samples, output_units) = (len(testX), 1)`.
3. `LSTM(activation='relu')` usually leads to instability when dealing with very large sequences. It's usually a good idea to leave it in `tanh`.